# Unmet dependencies during r installation (Debian)

Tags: r, debian

When I try to install r software in debian 10 I get unmet dependencies error.

```
The line "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/" was already added in "/etc/apt/sources.list".
```

After running "apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base", I get this message:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

I already tried the approaches from those sites:
https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/how-to-upgrade-to-R-4-0-0-on-debian/#the-naive-solution

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed in the file "/etc/apt/sources.list", where I have added the bellow links with the command line `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb link'`.

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
#deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
# deb-src http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` it should contain the regular debian repository and the `cran` repository (remove duplicate).

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for duplicate entry.

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base-core r-recommended r-base-html
sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base
```